# Does being in a clan impart any advantages?

Tags: clash-royale

What are the potential advantages and disadvantages of being a member of a clan within Clash-Royale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but only so much.

1. It enables you to give cards in exchange for experience and coins
2. More importantly it enables you to receive cards back. And people tend to give, if they have received. My clan leader gives quite a lot (and receives quite a lot too)
3. It enables you to play against real players for practice and not loose any trophies - sort of training against clan members.

Also a small community. You can ask for advice on the game and outside of it :D (Depending on the clan though)

It was quite difficult to find an English speaking clan before the global launch. It should be fine now.

Comment: Other advantages are friendly batters. These are helpful for trying new decks out and early access to challenges.